# How to group by single words and count average score for a list containing tuple items?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have this list (words and distances from Word2Vec). I want to group by single words and calculate their average score.

```
('marital', 0.5820825099945068)
('marital', 0.5401102304458618)
('marital', 0.5585618615150452)
('procreation', 0.5712854862213135)
('warship', 0.4743773341178894)
('benefactor', 0.48474687337875366)
('attended', 0.5120648145675659)
('parenthood', 0.6088712811470032)
('unmarried', 0.5549637079238892)
('unmarried', 0.5597274303436279)
('unmarried', 0.5792523622512817)
('collaborator', 0.5941322445869446)
('ex-wife', 0.7367603182792664)
('ex-wife', 0.6190139055252075)
('ex-wife', 0.6742737293243408)
```

Expected the result:

```
('marital', [average_score])
('procreation', 0.5712854862213135)
('warship', 0.4743773341178894)
('benefactor', 0.48474687337875366)
('attended', 0.5120648145675659)
('parenthood', 0.6088712811470032)
('unmarried', [average_score])
('collaborator', 0.5941322445869446)
('ex-wife', [average_score])
```

My method is to loop all items and add them and their scores to a dictionary and then count the average score. However, I wonder do we have more better ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your list to a data frame and use groupby to calculate the mean score.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list)
df.groupby([0]).agg("mean")
```

Output

```
              1
    0   
attended    0.512065
benefactor  0.484747
collaborator    0.594132
ex-wife     0.676683
marital     0.560252
parenthood  0.608871
procreation     0.571285
unmarried   0.564648
warship     0.474377
```

Answer (score 1):

Without third-party modules, Python provides the tools you need for this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
from statistics import mean

mylist = ... copy from question ...

results = []
# Group runs of values with identical words
for word, grp in groupby(mylist, key=itemgetter(0)):
    avg = mean(map(itemgetter(1), grp))  # Grab values for word and take their mean
    results.append((word, avg))
print(*results, sep="\n")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLLbtswEEX3@gohm0iFGvAxw0cBf0mbBW3TjhBJJCi6rr/eHZNxWzTmknNm7h3yxkt@C4u8Xg8pzO2YfcohTGs7zjGk3B5TOMXtpSnVEH1yOaR7kej56DP11PqaXR7XPO7@tM/eLU0zXya6bjft96Z7nl0as5ueh5a9oBHMCGTWWkCmTD/8DwDjnAnJANAo/gBAg3SvOHJkgKIAMYVd8uQlLBXSXBgEo4Tgkkss0Nml9W2MBQANUmspgXNtjIUCbP3iD25H@1bGEKUMUdpolEoVyNH2y97vqw4XTIHhgEqjQlvNuOQXeuNQGcWMudnhHDRjsho@LbRTGu9jEKySmmkrJLl5jFgtyDSTIJXQ9hFC7SioKvAmpwuyC9PktqH8YqUscClEeV4LUJfyv76ex4MvgJZKKya5IRWhFHwCFLeMS8sQSY5p/AxoEFpqYaUACcz0zWvTJL@eprzeMvHaHChS55D2A8UttuNyT11XgzO07/6y@Ru2jvX9t6al434eacItZN3sYvcPwvsyrO8L96H24mKk3@q6KkbdVI9pXHL35QMZ2tXHzdOP5am/Xn8D)

Note that `groupby`, unlike a `dict`-oriented solution, requires the grouped words to appear next to each other (so, for example, if you added a second `'procreation'` entry to the *end* of the input, it wouldn't be grouped with the one earlier).

If that's not guaranteed to be the case, you'd need to change `groupby(mylist, key=itemgetter(0))` to `groupby(sorted(mylist, key=itemgetter(0)), key=itemgetter(0))` to make it work, but that will cause the asymptotic runtime will suffer; `groupby` on presorted data is `O(n)` (impossible to beat asymptotically), a `dict`-based solution is expected case `O(n)` (worst case `O(n**2)`, but Python tries to defend against intentional attacks that could trigger it), while `groupby`+`sorted` is `O(n log n)`, making it worse than the expected `dict` performance.